# firefox save image with sequential number

Tags: firefox, rename

**Firefox:**
Is there a way  to automatically add a sequential number when saving files (especially images) **only** if the file with the same name already exists in target folder? I'm not necessarily looking for a 'mass-image-download' type of extension where you save a set of images with sequential numbers (although it would be fine if it solved my problem). I need only a simple functionality like in Chrome browser:

When:

`File_name.jpg`

exists in target folder the suggested file name in file save dialog automatically becomes:

`File_name (1).jpg`

and so on, so there is no need to rename files when unsure if the existing file is identical to the one being saved.

**UPDATE:**

My system: Windows 7, Firefox 33.1. Unfortunatelly I've never experienced FF renaming files the way I need.

Comment: This would happen by default on Windows.  Helps if we know the operating system.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'll update my answer.